# "Command" has no attribute "Load"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

I have a discord bot, but when I try to run one of the codes, it says "command" has no attribute "load" and if I fix that, it comes up with a ton of other JSON errors

I tried to not load and use the actual thing, but then another problem showed up. I'm using the discord.py rewrite with bot.commands and bot.events, and I am also using JSON

```py
def checkforprofile(userid):
    with open("gp.json", mode="r") as g:
        gp = json.load(g)
        user = "userid_" + str(userid)
        if user not in gp:
            addprofile(userid);
            print("Profile " + str(user) + "created");
            rules = discord.Embed(title=".",description='.')
            rules.add_field(name="**ADB** profile created!", value=":)")
            bot.get_user(userid).send(embed=rules)
        else: print("Profile creation request cancelled")
```

and here is the error I get:

```py
line 117, in checkforprofile
    gp = json.load(g)
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'load'
```

I want it to stop giving all the errors because when this gets fixed, it will probably give a new error
Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you created class/object with name `json` so now it can't use standard module `json`.

Comment: thanks! That fixed it- turns out one of my help commands ruined it